# How to perform numerical integration+space point process

Tags: integration, statistics

I want to integrate the following function:

$\int_{W}\eta^{1-B(u)}du$, where $\eta$ is a constant, $W$ corresponds to the observation window for the point process and

$B(u)=\frac{A_{w}(\textbf{x})-A_{w}(\textbf\{x\} \setminus \{u\}) }{\pi r^2}$

$A$ represents the area of a point pattern $\textbf{x}$ on $W$, $\eta$ is a constant and $u$ is a point on $W$

This is a cartoon of the thing:

[image]

I am trying to do this using the R package [polyCub](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=polyCub), but is not working, I appreciate any help

My attempt:

```
library(spatstat)
requireversion(spatstat, "1.41-1.073")

W <- as.owin(swedishpines)
x <- c(28,29,55,60,66)
#xp<-seq(W$xrange[1],)
y <- c(70,38,32,72,59)
X <- ppp(x=x,y=y, window = W)
u <- list(x=48,y=50)
u <- as.ppp(u, W)
rad <- 14
Xplusr <- dilation(X, rad) # 
uplusr <- disc(rad, u) 
ovlap <- intersect.owin(uplusr, Xplusr)
AIdemo <- layered(W, 
                  ovlap,
                  Xplusr,
                  uplusr,
                  X,
                  u)
layerplotargs(AIdemo) <- list(list(),
                              list(col="darkgrey", border=NA),
                              list(lwd=2),
                              list(lwd=2, lty=2),
                              list(pch=16),
                              list(pch=3))
plot(AIdemo)

library(polyCub)

f2<-function(s,etap=2){
    etap^{1-area(setminus.owin(disc(rad, s),Xplusr))/(pi*rad*rad)}
}

polyCub.SV(W,f2,nGQ=20)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `help("polyCub.SV")` says the following about the function to be integrated:

```
f: a two-dimensional real function (or ‘NULL’ to only compute
   nodes and weights). As its first argument it must take a
   coordinate matrix, i.e., a numeric matrix with two columns,
   and it must return a numeric vector of length the number of
   coordinates.
```

So if you define a suitable matrix-version of `f2` as

```
f2mat <- function (s, ...) apply(X = s, MARGIN = 1, FUN = f2, ...)
```

which calls the function `f2` for every row of the coordinate matrix `s`,
the integration routine

```
polyCub.SV(W, f2mat, nGQ=20)
```

will run without error and return 12047.26.

Note that since your integration domain `W` is rectangular, you might as well use the function `hcubature` (or `pcubature`) from the [cubature](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=cubature) package, which might be more efficient in that case.